# What happens when checkpoint_segments reached?

Tags: postgresql, checkpoint

I'm a bit confused with checkpoint_segments definition in PostgreSQL documentation. What happens when checkpoint_segments reached?

1. The dirty pages in shared_buffers written to WAL. Then what is the
   usage of background writer?
2. WAL is merged to actual data files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combing through the docs, I see the following (accidental incorrect details will hopefully (or surely) be pointed out by others):

> There is a separate server process called the background writer, whose
>   function is to issue writes of "dirty" (new or modified) shared
>   buffers.

BW does its work according to its config parameters.  It writes at most `bgwriter_lru_maxpages` dirty shared buffers, then has a `bgwriter_delay` millisecond rest.  Now, when it comes to `checkpoint_segments` **log** segments (or `checkpoint_timeout` seconds, if it comes first), it flushes **all** (remaining) dirty segments to data files.  Now the database data has a consistent state on disk, with a corresponding entry in the log as well.  It is a good starting point for a subsequent REDO if necessary.

And who does make the checkpoints?

> The server's background writer process automatically performs a
>   checkpoint [...]

As for your 2nd point, WAL is WAL (stored in log segment files) and data files are data files.  The two will be consistent with each other but not merged.

Comment: So `bgwriter` writes updates from shared bufferes to WAL and when `checkpoint_segments` reaches it flushes WAL files to main data files? right?

Comment: @MajidAzimi - _Briefly, WAL's central concept is that changes to data files (where tables and indexes reside) must be written only after those changes have been logged, that is, after log records describing the changes have been flushed to permanent storage._ ([source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-intro.html))  In other words, WAL shows what data files should contain, but never the affected rows themselves.